# Memory Management: Faulting virtual addresses

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

I came across the following on http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

> If the faulting virtual address is invalid this means that the process
>   has attempted to access a virtual address that it should not have.
>   Maybe the application has gone wrong in some way, for example writing
>   to random addresses in memory. In this case the operating system will
>   terminate it, protecting the other processes in the system from this
>   rogue process.

Now, my doubt is related to this phrase

> "faulting virtual address is invalid".

What is exactly meant by this? **How can a **virtual address be invalid****? After all, any 32 bit value (on a 32 bit machine) would correspond to some 'valid' address in the virtual address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any 32 bit value (on a 32 bit machine) would correspond to some 'valid' address in the virtual address space

Incorrect. Page entries can point to physical memory that doesn't exist or is marked off-limits, or they can contain an invalid pattern.

Comment: Ironically, the answer is there in the same sentence from which I picked up the quote. "If the faulting virtual address is invalid this means that the process has attempted to access a virtual address that it should not have." That explains what the author really means by a 'faulting virtual address'.